# How to implement "last seen at" functionality (like whatsapp) in XMPP?

Tags: xmpp

I am working on a chat application and want to add "last seen at" functionality. I am trying to implement it by using presence stanzas but getting one issue, please check at below link

[Not getting unavailable presence of User A when User B is also unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24446717/not-getting-unavailable-presence-of-user-a-when-user-b-is-also-unavailable?noredirect=1#comment37832724_24446717)

Is there any other way to implement last seen at functionality

please suggest

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first Google result for "xmpp last seen" is [XEP-0012: Last Activity](http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0012.html), which is a protocol extension that can be used to find out when a user was online last time.

You send a request like this:

```xml
<iq from='romeo@montague.net/orchard' 
    id='last1'
    to='juliet@capulet.com'
    type='get'>
  <query xmlns='jabber:iq:last'/>
</iq>
```

And get a response like this:

```xml
<iq from='juliet@capulet.com' 
    id='last1'
    to='romeo@montague.net/orchard'
    type='result'>
  <query xmlns='jabber:iq:last' seconds='903'/>
</iq>
```

Which means that the contact was last online 903 seconds ago.  Subtract this from the current time to get the "last seen" timestamp.

Comment: Thanks this is what i was searching could you please let me know how to implement XMPPLastActivity.h. I dont know how to use its methods

Comment: I don't have any experience with XMPPFramework, so you'd probably get better answers by posting that as a separate question.

Comment: Please DO NOT send a `jabber:iq:last` request to everyone on your roster, or your server will rate-limit you when you have a user with a realistic-sized roster.  Think more about when you need to send these and why.

Comment: by sending packet like above, I have receiving IQ with error 403 with type AUTH, 
 can anyone guide me, where I am missing ???

Answer (score 0):

**Last seen and Last Activity are two different scenarios.**

Last Activity is when user gone offline last time, but last seen is when user goes in background from the application in that case user will be available if application is not killed.You have to create new plugin on server side for last seen.

Answer (score 0):

The @legoscia solution  will return the last activity time, which is your last logout time(not the last time when user was online), plz check this https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/2265

> If the user has at least one connected or available resource when the server receives the request, the response MUST (subject to local security policies) contain an empty element whose 'seconds' attribute is set to a value of '0'.

One solution is to kill the session every time the app goes in background and reconnect when the app is in foreground