# Implementing Last seen Functionality in iOS using XMPP Stanza is not being sent

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp

I am working with an application which have chat like whatsapp and having the functionality of last seen I have refer this answer

[How to implement "last seen at" functionality (like whatsapp) in XMPP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24449966/how-to-implement-last-seen-at-functionality-like-whatsapp-in-xmpp)

I have implemented the code on the screen of chat like this

```
NSXMLElement *queryElement = [NSXMLElement elementWithName: @"query" xmlns: @"jabber:iq:last"];
 NSXMLElement *iqStanza = [NSXMLElement elementWithName: @"iq"];
    [iqStanza addAttributeWithName: @"type" stringValue: @"get"];
    [iqStanza addAttributeWithName:John@192.168.1.100  stringValue: @"from"];
    [iqStanza addAttributeWithName:Jacob@192.168.1.100 stringValue: @"to"];
    [iqStanza addAttributeWithName: @"last1" stringValue: @"id"];
    [iqStanza addChild: queryElement];
    [self.xmppStream sendElement:iqStanza];
```

but still I am not getting the last seen Can Any One please help me When I am doing wrong?
And neither being sent the stanza nor receiving the stanza of last seen.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In AppDelegate.h file import  XMPPLastActivity.h  and declare property of this class.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly)  XMPPLastActivity *xmppLastActivity;
```

and AppDelegate.m file for Xmpp's setupStream method alloc it and set delegate of xmpplastActivity and activate lastActivity Module

```
 xmppLastActivity = [[XMPPLastActivity alloc] initWithDispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    [xmppLastActivity addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [xmppLastActivity      activate:xmppStream];
```

and You have to called a method for which Jid you want the Last activity. And call like this

```
[xmppLastActivity sendLastActivityQueryToJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:FriendsJID]];
```

and you can get response in seconds in

```
- (void)xmppLastActivity:(XMPPLastActivity *)sender didReceiveResponse:(XMPPIQ *)response
{
    NSLog(@"last seen: %lu", (unsigned long)[response lastActivitySeconds]);
}
```

Hope This will help you in getting Last seen of the user.
 And last but in the least thanks @hardluckbaby to find out this.

Answer (score 4):

I think you got your "addAttributeWithName" values mixed up.

Are you using [this iOS XMPP Framework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/)?

If you have imported XMPPIQ and XMPPJID, you can try this:

```
XMPPIQ *lastActivity = [[XMPPIQ alloc] initWithType:@"get" to:[XMPPJID jidWithString:@"Jacob@192.168.1.100"]];
[lastActivity addAttributeWithName:@"from" stringValue:@"John@192.168.1.100"];
[lastActivity addAttributeWithName:@"id" stringValue:@"last1"];
[lastActivity addChild:[[XMPPIQ alloc] initWithName:@"query" xmlns:@"jabber:iq:last"]];
[self.xmppStream sendElement:lastActivity];
```

Or you can import XMPPLastActivity.h for this:

```
[xmppLastActivity sendLastActivityQueryToJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:@"Jacob@192.168.1.100"]];
```

If you want to stick with NSXMLElement:

```
NSXMLElement *iqStanza = [NSXMLElement elementWithName: @"iq"];
[iqStanza addAttributeWithName: @"type" stringValue: @"get"];
[iqStanza addAttributeWithName: @"from"  stringValue:@"John@192.168.1.100"];
[iqStanza addAttributeWithName: @"to" stringValue: @"Jacob@192.168.1.100"];
[iqStanza addAttributeWithName: @"id" stringValue: @"last1"];

NSXMLElement *queryElement = [NSXMLElement elementWithName: @"query" xmlns: @"jabber:iq:last"];
[iqStanza addChild: queryElement];

[self.xmppStream sendElement:iqStanza];
```

Your `attributeWithName` is the "field name" and `stringValue` is your parameter. Oh, and don't forget to enclose the strings with `@"{STRING HERE}"`.

**EDIT:**

As for the response, I think you will get it from:

```
- (void)xmppLastActivity:(XMPPLastActivity *)sender didReceiveResponse:(XMPPIQ *)response {        
}
```

Provided you have set the delegate (if you set this up on your **setUpStream** method):

```
xmppLastActivity = [[XMPPLastActivity alloc] initWithDispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[xmppLastActivity addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[xmppLastActivity activate:xmppStream];
```

There are convenience methods declared in XMPPIQ+LastActivity.h, but I'm not sure how to use them. Just try logging the response.

```
- (void)xmppLastActivity:(XMPPLastActivity *)sender didReceiveResponse:(XMPPIQ *)response {
    NSLog(@"last activity: %lu", (unsigned long)[response lastActivitySeconds]);
    NSLog(@"response: %@", response);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your Reply . I have added  as you told  XMPPLastActivity *xmppLastActivity = [[XMPPLastActivity alloc]init];
    [xmppLastActivity sendLastActivityQueryToJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:@"Jacob@192.168.1.100"]];   please will you tell me where can I get the response of stanza? Many thanks.

Comment: @hardluckybaby  Yes I am using  the         https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/.

Comment: @hardluckybaby thanks a lot I m join to use this and let you know if it works or not.... will you tell me [xmppLastActivity addDelegate:sharedClient delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[xmppLastActivity activate:xmppStream]; What is sharedClient???

Comment: @ArbazShaikh sorry that's supposed to be SELF or the class where you declared your XMPPStream

Comment: This do work but seconds are not updated even if user gets online couple of times :(

Answer (score 0):

These lines look odd:

```
[iqStanza addAttributeWithName:John@192.168.1.100  stringValue: @"from"];
[iqStanza addAttributeWithName:Jacob@192.168.1.100 stringValue: @"to"];
[iqStanza addAttributeWithName: @"last1" stringValue: @"id"];
```

It looks like you've got the name and the value the wrong way around — the names are `from`, `to` and `id`, and the values are `John@192.168.1.100`, `Jacob@192.168.1.100` and `last1`.

Furthermore, as a client, you don't need to add the `from` attribute; the server will do it for you.  However, if you do provide an incorrect `from` attribute, the server will reject the stanza.

Comment: but as XEP-0012 Last Activity  we have to send <iq from='romeo@montague.net/orchard' 
    id='last1'
    to='juliet@capulet.com'
    type='get'>
  <query xmlns='jabber:iq:last'/>
</iq>    thats why i am sending "from" like this.

Comment: The examples in that XEP show what the stanzas look like after the server has added the `from` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for reply but will you help me what should I have to do to get last seen I have tried it and showed what I have done. It will be great help if you help me in this.

Comment: Get the XML dump of the actual stanzas being sent between the client and the server, and put that into your question.  That should hopefully show what's going wrong.

Comment: actually that is what I am actually asking How to send the stanza of getting last seen, between client and server?

Comment: So the code posted above doesn't send any stanza at all? That would be useful information to include in the question.  (Also any error messages or exceptions.)

Comment: yes this code May not send any stanza may be thats why I am not receiving it. Please help me to send it.

Comment: I'm not sure why that might happen; I don't have any experience with Objective-C.  If you edit your question to include the fact that nothing is being sent, that will help someone more knowledgeable to answer the question.